# Alignment of ARCore with GPS

Tags: java, android, gps, arcore, geopositioning

[image]I recorded GPS and ARCore for outdoor positioning. However in several cases when I plot the trajectories from both GPS and ARCore, they do not align and there is a angle of rotation of about 120 degrees to 60 degrees in some cases, and some are perfectly matched.

Now the question is as there isn't a universal phase difference, how can we match these two trajectories? I believe ARCore renders the heading quite random without any underlying rule and due to the noisy sensors, like compass.
I added a picture for a sample outdoor trajectory.

Comment: Graphing like that is a great idea - interesting how closely the shapes match. Can you share he code you use to plot the AR position and it may help others answer you.

Comment: It is just a simple plotting of x, y coordinates from GPS and ARCore.

Comment: ARCore is a localized refinement of your position. GPS points are not that locally refined. You should use ARCore's camera pose between two GPS points if you wish to integrate the two.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. There are two issues with this approach: 1- GPS has error and the drift from ARCore is lower. I need the accuracy in the scale of ARCore. 2- For indoor the GPS is not available.